# Code Coverage Details within TFS

Tags: tfs, code-coverage, tfsbuild

We are using the Team Foundation Server 2015 and our build task uses [Report Generator](https://github.com/danielpalme/ReportGenerator) for generating the Code Coverage view.
Now we are trying to get something similar without any third party libraries.

If I look at the build details, under the section "Code Coverage", I have two charts (Blocks and Lines) and beneath these a link "Download Code Coverage Results". And that's all. If I download the file and open it with Visual Studio I can see the details.

Is there any built-in way to generate a webpage or anything else which shows more details on the TFS itself?

Comment: You'd be looking at writing your own custom task to do this.  Have you considered integrating SonarQube with your build?  There is nice integration with TFS/VSTS builds and you'll get a dashboard with code coverage/code analysis and more.  You get a link added to the TFS build report which will take you straight to the dashboard (although it is still outside of TFS)

Answer (score 0):

There is no out of box feature for this, you can submit a feature request on [VSTS User Voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services).